# Edit CSV data before sending to sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I have externalized my input with the help of CSV Data Set Config.

I'm trying to modify the value read from CSV before sending it to my sampler in jmeter

Sample example

For simple understanding, my CSV file has following information

${Today},Test Information
${Tomorrow}, Test Information 2

In bean shell preprocessor I'm saving the today(02/sep/2021) and tomorrow(03/Sep/2021) date in the variable today and tomorrow but when the sampler gets executed, it's still having ${Today} and ${Tomorrow} rather than having 02/Sep/2021 and 03/Sep/2021

I'm trying to pass dynamic values for the variable available in csv

Comment: Why do you want to write the test data (today and tomorrow) into a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

1. [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are **case sensitive** so `Today` and `today` are different entities and you need to mind the case
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to Groovy
3. You can get today and tomorrow dates in various formats using [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) and [__timeShift()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function/) functions, there is no need to use any CSV files or go for scripting

   [image]